# How do I update Itext7 to version 7.1.1

Tags: eclipse, maven, itext7

This seems like it should be simple but I cannot find anything on how to upgrade to newer versions of itext7. I am using an Eclipse maven project with itext7 version 7.0.4 and would like to update to 7.1.1. However, I can find nothing that tells me how to do that. Neither the Eclipse update menu or the Maven menu has an option to update itext7. Can someone point me to the documentation on how to do an update? TIA.

After answer:

I am not getting the libraries but instead getting conflicts:

[image]

I can't seem to post my pom.xml using code tags (I guess the formatter has a problem with XML code because of the <>) but I will include it if someone tells me how. I've uploaded the pom file to DropBox:
[pom.xml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s0ebsjb76wh4u8t/pom.xml?dl=0)

Comment: In your project there is a file pom.xml which contains the maven project definition. In there is a dependencies section with entries for the iText artefacts  (among others). The version is therein. Well, it could also be in a separate dependencies management section or in a parent pom.xml referenced in your file.

Comment: But don't I have to download the jar file from somewhere and install it somewhere?

Comment: As soon as you update the pom file, you can update the  eclipse project configuration in your eclipse maven menu. That will, if necessary, automatically download the jar artefacts. If your eclipse maven integration is properly configured, that is, and if your computer has proper internet connectivity.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Will it also clean up old versions no longer needed?

Comment: It will remain in your local repository but won't be in the class path anymore.

Comment: @mkl can you turn your combined comments into an answer so it can be upvoted?

Comment: I also recommend that you put the iText version in a `<properties>` section in your `pom.xml`. Take a look at our example snippet to get an idea: https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/Java

Comment: your edit clearly shows that the 7.1.1 artefacts are used, doesn't it?

Comment: That's what I would have thought but all my Java imports (e.g. import com.itextpdf.awt.PdfGraphics2D;) cannot be resolved.

Comment: Once you successfully update your pom file from iText 7.0.4 to 7.1.1, there is a chance your code will also require changes.  I saw so many conflicts that I delayed migrating to 7.1.1.  I find it frustrating that 7.1.1 is not backward compatible with 7.0.5.  I understood from 5 to 7, but a dot release?!?!

Comment: This is most weird. Perhaps an Eclipse glitch. After 2 days of fighting this, the import errors magically went away. I don't know what to make if it but all seems OK now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Turning @mkl's and @amedee's comments into an answer)

In your project there is a file `pom.xml` which contains the Maven project definition. In there is a dependencies section with entries for the iText artifacts (among others). The version is therein. Well, it could also be in a separate dependencies management section or in a parent `pom.xml` referenced in your file.

As soon as you update the POM file, you can update the Eclipse project configuration in your Eclipse Maven menu. That will, if necessary, automatically download the jar artifacts. If your Eclipse Maven integration is properly configured, that is, and if your computer has proper internet connectivity.

Old versions will remain in your local repository but won't be in the class path anymore.

Also check out our getting started guide. Which contains an example POM snippet.
https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/Java

If you put your iText version number in POM properties, then you only have to update the value once when you want to upgrade. Like this:

```
<properties>
  <itext.version>7.1.1</itext.version>
</properties>
```

and then

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>io</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure what I have at this point. I think it updated but did not pull the libraries into my project. I've updated the OP with my results.